# How to match the portion after first occurance of a word in python

Tags: python, regex

For example, input string:

```
In North Dighton, there's a Flash Flood Watch in effect until Wednesday, July 12, 9:00 PM.
```

I want to extract the following string out

```
North Dighton
```

So I write python code like this:

```
found_group = re.search('(.*)in (.*?),(.*)', "In North Dighton, there's a Flash Flood Watch in effect until Wednesday, July 12, 9:00 PM.", re.IGNORECASE)

fround_group.group(2)
```

however it outputs:

```
effect until Wednesday
```

How can only match the portion between the first "in" and the first comma?

**Attention, the first "in" might not be the first word of the line.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use negated character class to not to match `,` but any character. Because `.*` in your regex is greedy which will ate any no of character until a match found or make `.*` non-greedy like `.*?`

```
found_group = re.search('([^,]*)in ([^,]*),(.*)', "In North Dighton, there's a Flash Flood Watch in effect until Wednesday, July 12, 9:00 PM.", re.IGNORECASE)
fround_group.group(2)
```

[Demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/QheZDn/1)
[Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/QheZDn/2)

Comment: I see even this works: found_group = re.search('(.*?)in (.*?),(.*)', "In North Dighton, there's a Flash Flood Watch in effect until Wednesday, July 12, 9:00 PM.", re.IGNORECASE)

Answer (score 0):

t = "In North Dighton, there's a Flash Flood Watch in effect until Wednesday, July 12, 9:00 PM"

```
import re
re.search(r'In (.+?),', t).group(1)
```

o/p

'North Dighton'